# Insert or update if exists into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Table structure.

```
id, uid, prodid, price
1    1     123   10 
2    2     123   20  
3    3     123   40
```

In this case product id are same for all users.
e.g prod id - 123  for user 1, 2, 3 ....
I want to import csv file having product price changed or it may be new product for particular user.

In this case product should be insert if not present for particular user and should update if already exists.

**Myql query**

- insert into table_name (prodid, uid, price) values('123',10, 100) on duplicate key
- update price = IF(uid = values(uid), values(price), price)

In this - added unique constraints for - prodid.

Pls. help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: try to use `REPLACE INTO on DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` -- just a tip ;)

Comment: For unique key it will search prodid and not insert even if uid is different.

Answer (score 0):

1. change your 'uid' to unique ['screenshoot unique in phpMyAdmin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNPfd.png)
2. try this query : ['screenshoot query in phpMyAdmin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3BjF.png)

> insert into table_name (prodid, uid, price) values('123',2, 100) on
>   duplicate key update price = values(price)

Happy coding..